# Get document property from script in google apps script

Tags: properties, google-apps-script, google-apps

I have an addon which stores Properties in google documents.
I developed this addon and I used `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()`.

Now I wrote a standalone google apps script which needs to iterate on every doc in a specific folder and, for each doc, to get the stored properties.

I'm trying to use the same `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties()` function but it seems that `PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties()` is returning *NULL*.

```
var documentProperties =  PropertiesService.getDocumentProperties().getProperties();
```

Is it possible to call it from a standalone google apps script? how can I set the active document?

Otherwise, how can I get all properties I stored in each of the different docs?

Comment: those are properties per script. you are using a different script.

Comment: Yes, I know it. So is not possible to access Document's properties from a standalone script in any way?

Comment: if you find one id consider it a security bug. your only option is to export elsewhere from the addon.